# Compare that BigDecimal value and double value are equal to two decimal places

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

I'm working with an API that returns a double value. I need to compare that value to a BigDecimal value for equality to two decimal places.

Should I convert BigDecimal to double and then compare

```
Math.abs(myBigDecimal.doubleValue() - apiDouble) >= .01
```

Or are there issues with this approach? Perhaps I should convert the double into a BigDecimal and and then compare?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Although IEEE double has guard bits, it cannot exactly represent a decimal value. Convert the double to a BigDecimal, using rounding, and then use compareTo(). Note that equals() takes into account decimal positions, so compareTo() is safer. You may need to round the BigDecimal as well.

Comment: Can you provide example values where the code in the OP would not work?

Comment: As I said, IEEE double has guard bits that make creating an example difficult. In addition, rounding a double to two decimal places requires a certain amount of fiddling. BigDecimal was created for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Shift desired decimal positions multiplying both doubles by 100, use Math.ceil or Math.floor, as you prefer, to get rid by the rest of decimal positions:

```
Math.ceil(myBigDecimal.doubleValue()*100) == Math.ceil(apiDouble*100)
```

this is equivalent to truncate without rounding.
If you are worring about rounding, multiply by 1000, cast to long divide by 10 and compare.